# Is there a Cordova equivalent of the Electron <webview> tag?

Tags: ios, cordova, iframe, wkwebview

I'm having all kinds of issues with iframes in Cordova with little success.

In Electron, you can [embed a webview in your application using a `<webview>` tag](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/webview-tag/) -- is there any equivalent in the Cordova world?

If nothing exists yet, any ideas how I might go about building this ontop of WKWebView?

Comment: InAppBrowser plugin is a webview, not sure if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm looking for something embedded in my webpage. Like a youtube video embed.

Comment: No, cordova doesn't have anything like that

Comment: Oy vey. Is there no way to use iframes then?

Comment: yeah, you can use iframes using the iframe tag